# UnAuthorized exception when trying to get folder name

Tags: c#

I tried to extract all my files and folders starting in c:\ to a tree data structure.
I get an UnAuthorized exception for some directories.
Is there another solution to check to see if I have permission to a folder?

I also tried using directoryName.Exists - it did not work.

my code:

```
private static void getAllFilesAndFoldersInPath(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Items.Clear();

        var stack = new Stack<TreeViewItem>();
        var rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        TreeViewItem node = new TreeViewItem();
        node.Header = rootDirectory;
        stack.Push(node);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentNode = stack.Pop();
            var directoryInfo = (DirectoryInfo)currentNode.Header;

            try
            {
                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    if (!directory.Name.StartsWith("$"))
                    {
                        TreeViewItem childDirectoryNode = new TreeViewItem();
                        childDirectoryNode.Header = directory;
                        currentNode.Items.Add(childDirectoryNode);
                        stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Name).StartsWith("~$") || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.Name) == ".tmp")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    TreeViewItem tempNode = new TreeViewItem();
                    tempNode.Header = file;
                    currentNode.Items.Add(tempNode);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) { }
        }
        treeView.Items.Add(node);
    }
```

Comment: Path that you pass to the function is permitted for the user of the application?

Comment: you seem to think that the exceptions due to unauthorized are slowing you down a lot. Not likely, although exceptions cost a bit the cost is not huge. They are very expensive if you run in the debugger but not otherwise. The reason it takes a minute is becuase you look at every file in the system. You would be better off passing the file mask to the getfile call

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use EnumerateDirectories instead of GetDirectories.  Much, **much** faster.
2. In your catch statement - *do something with the exception*.  Don't just let the code swallow it, this is bad programming.

I have a handy little method I wrote awhile back that works well for me, feel free to give it a spin:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(DirectoryInfo workingDirectory, 
                                   string searchPattern, 
                                   bool recursive = false) 
                                   where T : FileSystemInfo
    {
        var results = workingDirectory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(searchPattern,
            recursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        return results.OfType<T>();
    }
```

Where in your case you might call it like this:

```
var dirTree = Find<DirectoryInfo>(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"), "*", true);
```